# SlimPHP: How to pass array of flash messages to twig template

Tags: php, twig, slim

I would like to send an array of flash messages to a twig template. The code would go like this:

```
$errors = $validation->errors();
$app->flash('error', $errors);
$app->response->redirect($app->urlFor('register'), 303);
```

This is what I've tried in the twig template, but it doesn't render the messages:

```
{% for error in flash.error %}
    {{ error }}
{% endfor %}
```

`var_dump($errors)` does show me the different error messages. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the content of the register callback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up having to use the "for key" construct from twig. Below is how the code looks now:

```
{% for key,  error in flash.error %}
    <li><em>{{ error }}</em></li>
{% endfor %}
```

Hope this helps someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var_dump($flash);die();
```